# more problems with the hyundai entourage

Tags: hyundai, van

thank you for the help on my last question. we ran into some more issues with the 2007 hyundai entourage. did what you had said with the transmission arm and linkage. yet the van wont start. so I started at the fuses and sure enough there were several that were blown,one of which is the ignition fuse another was the AMT fuse.  okay I know this should be simple enough. take outthe old and put in new, right? not so easy. the ignition fuse slides in and out no effort needed. so it won't make a connection. I have very little experience with electrical especially in a vehicle. I do t want to fry any computers or sensors. how can I get my mom back on the road? please anyone know what to do?

Comment: Are you looking at a permanent fix or just to get going.

Comment: permanent fix., its for my mom who is disabled

Comment: Then the answer below should get it done.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to get to the back of the fuse pannel. Stick a bright colored wire tie through where the fuse plugs in. See if you can find the wire tie from the back, make sure both wire terminals are in the socket still if not put it back in. If they both appear to still be in there place, remove them using a pin puller, check to see if the terminals are scorched or just worn and spread apart. If they are just spread apart or lightly worn, gently squeeze it back together. If it is burnt you must put a new end on.